# Integrate Sendgrid with Symfony2

Tags: php, symfony, sendgrid

I have a problem trying to integrate sendgrid library in Symfony2. We have copied the library inside our bundle and we have included it in a service. If this service is called by an action, the library it is running successfully.

This is the service:

```
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerInterface;

require_once(__DIR__.'/SendgridPhp/sendgrid-php.php');

class MailerService extends \Twig_Extension {
    protected $container;
    private $mailer;
    private $templating;

    public function __construct(ContainerInterface $container,$mailer,$templating)
    {
        $this->container= $container;
        $this->mailer = $mailer;
        $this->templating=$templating;
    }

    public function sendEmail($to, $from, $subject, $body, $attachment = null)
    {   
        $sendgrid = new \SendGrid($this->container->getParameter('sendgrid_user'),  $this->container->getParameter('sendgrid_password'));

        $email = new \SendGrid\Email();

        $email->setFrom($from)
                ->setFromName('Name')
                ->setSubject($subject)
                ->addTo($to)
                ->setHtml($body, 'text/html');

        $salida = $sendgrid->send($email );
    }
}
```

The problem happens when we call this service from a symfony2 command.

```
  $mailerService = $container->get('mailer.service');
  $mailerService->sendEmail($user->getEmail(), $container->getParameter("sender_email"), 'Message', $body);
```

The error in namespace is the next:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Class 'SendGrid\Email' not found in /var/www/SpainStartup/src/SpainStartup/CommunicationBundle/Services/MailerService.php on line 35
```

Should we do something special to load the library in command context ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: *"We have copied the library inside our bundle"* - Sounds fishy. Provide it via your composer configuration as dependency, then autoloading should be available. (Which be just common, in your Bundle = only your code, that is the code you write).

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to autoload the library. The files for third-party code usually go in the vendor folder. You can add it to your composer.json in the `require` section:

```
{
    "require": {
        // Other dependencies...
        "sendgrid/sendgrid": "2.0.5"
    }
}
```

Remove what you "copied" in. Then run `composer update` wherever your composer.json file is located.

After this it should 'just work'.

Comment: Composer update command doesn't work for me. What am I missing here? I use mac, and I run the commands through terminal.

Answer (score -1):

Instead of using any sendgrid's library, I just worked upon the php example they provided on the api site. This stand-alone php code works flawlessly for me:

**sendmail.php**

```
<?php
function sendgridmail($from, $to, $subject, $message, $headers)
{
    print_r('entering the function');
    $url = 'https://api.sendgrid.com/';
    $user='shinujacob';
    $pass='mypassword';

    $params = array(
        'api_user'  => $user,
        'api_key'   => $pass,
        'to'        => $to,
        'subject'   => $subject,
        'html'      => '',
        'text'      => $message,
        'from'      => $from,
      );

    $request =  $url.'api/mail.send.json';

    // Generate curl request
    $session = curl_init($request);

    // Tell curl to use HTTP POST
    curl_setopt ($session, CURLOPT_POST, true);

    // Tell curl that this is the body of the POST
    curl_setopt ($session, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $params);

    // Tell curl not to return headers, but do return the response
    curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);

    curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        //print_r('obtaining the response');
    // obtain response
    $response = curl_exec($session);
    print_r('closing curl session');
    curl_close($session);

    // print everything out

    //print_r($response);

}



//only for testing:
/*$to      = 'shinujacobrocks@yahoo.com';
$subject = 'Testemail';
$message = 'It works!!';
echo 'To is: ' + $to;
#wp_mail( $to, $subject, $message, array() );
sendgridmail($to, $subject, $message, array());
print_r('Just sent!');*/
```